# how to update bios after RAM change - dell inspiron 1420 - Linux Mint 13

Tags: dell, ram

I have a Dell Inspiron 1420 with Linux Mint 13 on it (Ubuntu 12.11 I think). I have two sticks of RAM 1GB each. Today, I have changed one for a 2GB one. On boot, BIOS noticed RAM change and redirect me to BIOS setup - to change settings so system knows RAM has changed. Couldn't find out how to do it so resume normal boot. Running `free -m` shows me `Mem:           992` which means the new RAM stick of 2GB has not be recognized and Mint is running with only 1GB of RAM.

On Dell website found instructions on how to update the BIOS but it requires Windows. I have also check the linux.dell.com web site but it does not support Debian yet. Right now I am installing Windows on VirtualBox but anyone knows how to do it from Mint?

Thanks!

Comment: [ubuntu.se] is only for questions about Ubuntu. Other non-official Ubuntu flavours are not on-topic here. Please read the [faq]. You might want to try our friends in [unix.se] or [su] for assistance.

Comment: Linux mint is off-topic. I suggest checking out [Unix and Linux](http://Unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @jokerdino jrg noted for futur use!

Comment: **@jokerdino** As the question (and my answer) equally applies for Ubuntu, I answered anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most BIOS will prompt (to save new settings) when RAM or devices are changed.

Please check if this **not** the case for the Dell machine.

---

If this laptop does need a BIOS update, then there may only be a Windows or DOS (command line) software application to do so.

Look elsewhere (not Ubuntu forum) for how to create a boot CD (or floppy) to run the update software (typically under DOS).

Comment: Thanks! I actually replace the 2GB by the 1GB, reboot, halt, put the 2GB back, reboot, hit f5 on BIOS prompt and it now works!